# Sammy Title plugin not working with Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, sammy.js

I'm just getting started with Sammy and Knockout. I've defined a simple array of pages/routes within my view model as well as my routes:

```
(function($) {
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.chosenRoute = ko.observable();
        self.viewData = ko.observable();

        self.pages = [
            {'title': 'Home', 'route': '#/'},
            {'title': 'Job Candidates', 'route': '#/job-candidates'},
            ...
        ];

        self.goToPage = function(page) {
            location.hash = page.route;
        };

        Sammy(function() {
            this.use('Title');
            this.setTitle('Vintage Services');  // Doesn't work

            this.get('#/', function(context) {
                self.chosenRoute('#/');
                context.render('/static/templates/home.html', null,
                    self.viewData);
                window.document.title = 'Vintage Services'; // Works
            });

            this.get('', function() {
                this.app.runRoute('get', '#/');
            });
        }).run();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
})(jQuery);
```

I've included the Sammy Title plugin in my template, and I'm not getting any errors, but the plugin won't set the title. If I use `window.document.title`, it works. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Title plugin](https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/plugins/sammy.title.js) comes with two method:

> `setTitle` allows setting a global title or a function that modifies the title for each route/page.

So in itself it does not set the page title, you need to use the the plugin second method:

> *Helper* title() sets the document title, passing it through the function defined by setTitle() if set.

So to actual modify the title you need to use the `title` helper inside your routes:

```
 this.get('', function() {
            this.title('Vintage Services');
            this.app.runRoute('get', '#/');
        });
```

Or if you want to have always 'Vintage Services' in the title you can use the `setTitle` like before

```
this.setTitle('Vintage Services'); //so this call does not set the title

this.get('', function() {
    this.title(); // this call sets the title to 'Vintage Services'
    //this.title('Main'); //this call sets the title to 'Vintage Services Main'
    this.app.runRoute('get', '#/');
});
```

Note: If your are using the official Sammy plugins the `this.use('Title');` and `this.use(Sammy.Title);` calls are equivalent.

Comment: Gotcha. It doesn't throw an error, but it's also not working as expected. The initial `this.setTitle('Foo');` isn't working either. Something else I've noticed is that my `around` filter doesn't fire when the app runs, but it will on subsequent route invocations.

Comment: @Brandon after reading through the documentation. I've realized the problem is not with your `use('Title');` so see my update answer.

Comment: Ah! So, the entire problem was that I wasn't calling `this.title()` in my default route. Now everything works as expected. Thanks!